# MYSQL Order by with case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a Product Table which has following structure.

```
   ProductID     ProductName     ProductType
   1             Irrigation      1  
   2             Landscape       2  
   3             Sleeving        3  
   4             Planting        4
```

Now i need to returns rows in order of product type 3,2,4,1
For this i used MYSQL FIELD method which works fine like this

```
   Select * from product order by FIELD(producttype,3,2,4,1)
```

This is working fine,

My problem is if the productname is empty for producttype 3, then it should take next productname which is not empty, so in such case result order should be 2,4,1,3.

So first condition is records need to be in following order of product type

```
Sleeving      3
Landscape     2
Planting      4
Irrigation    1
```

But if Productname for producttype 3 is empty then order need to be

```
Landscape     2
Planting      4
Irrigation    1
              3
```

And further Productname for producttype 2 is empty then order need to be

```
Planting      4
Irrigation    1
              3
              2
```

From this result i just need to pick first record.

I hope i clear my point

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is it possible to add a column with the sequence order? if yes, you just have to filter out the empty names through a where clause and order by the new sequence column, limited to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will satisfy the specification:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(ProductName,'') IS NULL, FIELD(producttype,3,2,4,1)
```

The first expression will return a 1 if the ProductName is "empty" (NULL or zero length string'), otherwise it will return 0.

So, this will sort all the non-empty ProductName first, followed by the empty ProductName.

And then, it will sort by the original expresssion.

Note that this approach preserves the originally specified order, when there are two or more (or all) empty ProductName.

(The test for "empty" could be extended to include other cases, for example, using the TRIM() function as well.

---

The expression

```
NULLIF(ProductName,'') IS NULL
```

is shorthand, it's equivalent SQL-92 compliant:

```
CASE WHEN ProductName = '' OR ProductName IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

(And there are other ways to get the same result.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from product order by  
ISNULL(PRODUCTNAME),FIELD(producttype,3,2,4,1);
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3701/1)

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa18a/1 .. see the fiddle. Please be more clear in the clause 'later case.'

Answer (score 0):

Should work !

```
 SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY FIELD(IF(ProductName is null,0,producttype),1,3,2,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex query  and will never <sup>[citation needed]</sup> work as you need, because it should identity the next value in another row which can be anything. It is possible with views, functions, pivoting and many joins but as the number of rows, I dont think it can give a result.

However, to answer directly, **YES** Order BY with CASE is possible

```
Select * from product order by 
   CASE WHEN productname IS NULL then FIELD(producttype, 2, 4, 1, 3)
   CASE WHEN productname IS NOT NULL THEN FIELD(producttype, 3, 2, 4, 1)
```

**Again,** This is not full query and is not the solution

If your rows are limited you can chain up your queries like this

```
Select * from product order by 
   CASE WHEN productname IS NULL then FIELD(producttype, 2, 4, 1, 3)
   CASE WHEN (SELECT productname n FROM product WHERE producttype = '2') IS NULL THEN FIELD (4, 1, 3, 2)
```

As you see I have fixed the query to search for the row with '2' as product type in it. You can know them by making another query and pivoting it the main query.

**Again it is not neccessary**, process the rows server side it will very very easier than this.

Answer (score -1):

You Can Try this

Select * from product where ProductName!='' order by FIELD(producttype,3,2,4,1)

Comment: This excludes rows. I think the OP wanted the rows ordered, not filtered.